# Need advice regarding RMAN's working

Tags: oracle, rman

I have configured a RMAN script which first takes the backup of the database and then deletes the obsolete backupsets according to the present retention policy.Now is there any possibility of the given scenario

Scenario: The backup process starts and failed abruptly dues to some reason creating incomplete backupset.Then the backup deletion part of script runs and deletes the latest full/working backup(not the one that failed but the one which the script created on the previous run)of the database provided that the retention policy is redundancy 1.Hence I lose the only available/working backup of my database.

Can it happen?

Answer (score 1):

It will only delete the earlier backup if the current one is successful. 
You can try doing a full backup, cancel it and do list backup.

Answer (score 1):

With redundancy 1, rman will decide if for every single data file, at least one alternative exists that is suitable for restauration. Only if consistent additional copies are made of the same piece of information rman will decide all but one copy (and keep the latest).